# Illegal start of type in while loop

Tags: java, while-loop

I just started programming in java for school.(I already coded in Python and HTML/CSS.) I don't have much time and kind of doing it in a hurry. I don't understand everything that I am doing and every explication would be appreciated. I didn't really get the static and the public thing. Anyway, my main problem at the moment is that I got many errors on my while loop. Could you please help me fix this? Thank you. Here's my code and errors.

```
import java.util.scanner;

public class happy_tree {
    public static class constants{
    public static final string draw_char = "|";
    public static final int max_height = 40;
    public static final int min_height = 5;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        tree_height = get_user_input();
    }
    public static class get_user_input{
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (!reader.hasNextInt() && !tree_height<=max_height && tree_height>=min_height) {
            System.out.println("Veuillez entrer la hauteur du sapin à dessiner: ");
            tree_height = reader.nextInt();
            if (!reader.hasNextInt()){
                System.out.println("Veuillez entrer un nombre entier.");
            }else if (tree_height>max_height){
                System.out.println("Veuillez entrer une valeur entre 5 et 40.");
            }else if (tree_height<min_height){
                System.out.println("Veuillez entrer une valeur entre 5 et 40.");
            }
        }
        return int tree_height;
    }
}
```

And the errors:

```
Main.java:14: error: illegal start of type
        while (!reader.hasNextInt() && !tree_height<=max_height && tree_height>=min_height) {
        ^
Main.java:14: error: illegal start of type
        while (!reader.hasNextInt() && !tree_height<=max_height && tree_height>=min_height) {
               ^
Main.java:14: error: ')' expected
        while (!reader.hasNextInt() && !tree_height<=max_height && tree_height>=min_height) {
                ^
Main.java:14: error: ';' expected
        while (!reader.hasNextInt() && !tree_height<=max_height && tree_height>=min_height) {
                      ^
Main.java:14: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
        while (!reader.hasNextInt() && !tree_height<=max_height && tree_height>=min_height) {
                       ^
Main.java:14: error: ';' expected
        while (!reader.hasNextInt() && !tree_height<=max_height && tree_height>=min_height) {
                                   ^
Main.java:25: error: illegal start of type
        return int tree_height;
        ^
Main.java:25: error: ';' expected
        return int tree_height;
              ^
Main.java:25: error: <identifier> expected
        return int tree_height;
```

Comment: `public static final string draw_char = "|";` That should be `public static final String draw_char = "|";`

Comment: I don't think this is a dup, as the op mixed upclass and method definition, not assignment. the 'duplicate' question presents a solution not applicable here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used a class declaration where you wanted a method:

```
 public void get_user_input() {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (!reader.hasNextInt() && !tree_height<=max_height && tree_height>=min_height) {
            System.out.println("Veuillez entrer la hauteur du sapin à dessiner: ");
            tree_height = reader.nextInt();
            if (!reader.hasNextInt()){
                System.out.println("Veuillez entrer un nombre entier.");
            }else if (tree_height>max_height){
                System.out.println("Veuillez entrer une valeur entre 5 et 40.");
            }else if (tree_height<min_height){
                System.out.println("Veuillez entrer une valeur entre 5 et 40.");
            }
        }
        return int tree_height;
    }
```

Instead of another inner class.

Besides that, please follow the Java naming conventions for classes, methods, variables. In Java, while allowed, it is not common and discouraged to use the "underline-seperation" style, referred to as *snake_case*.  In Java, camelcase is used. That is, class names start with upper case, and continue lowercase. On each word you start uppercase again.

Methods and variables start lowercase and constants are all upper.

```
public class HappyTree { ...  // class : Upper case start, camel case

    public static class Constants {
        public static final String DRAW_CHAR = "|";  // constant, all upper, underscore allowed

        ...


    public void getUserInput() { // methods: start lower, camel case

     ...
```